# Printing pattern or specific rhythmic values with Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, printing, iteration

I am working on one website design and I am stuck at one point. I want to print `0` and `1` Values using JS only. Pattern should be like

```
010110100101
```

On every 4 iterations, it is changing its starting position. Like

`0101` - `1010` - `0101` - & goes on...

Help would be appreciated!

**My attempt:**

```
var max_num = 32; // Max number - it can vary
for (var x = 0; x < max_num; x++ ) {
    if( x % 2 == 0){
        document.write('0');
    } else {
        document.write('1');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried many times differently. But not coming near it but I start with for loop like this:

var max_num = 32; // Max number - it can vary
for (var x = 0; x < max_num; x++ ){

if( x % 2 == 0){}

document.write('0');

} else {}

Comment: Is the pattern always just like that, binary and toggling? For example, could the starting value be `abcd`, requiring `bcda`, `cdab`, `dabc`?

Answer (score 0):

**Correcting your code:**

In your loop, the condition `x % 2 == 0` should change it's value each 4 iterations. You can achieve that like:

```
x % 2 === Math.floor(x / 4) % 2
```

`Math.floor(x / 4) % 2` will change its value each 4 iteration, thus we are using it to alter the condition.

demonstration:

```
x    | x % 2 | Math.floor(x / 4) % 2 | condition | value to print
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0    | 0     | 0                     | true      | 0
1    | 1     | 0                     | false     | 1
2    | 0     | 0                     | true      | 0
3    | 1     | 0                     | false     | 1
4    | 0     | 1                     | false     | 1
5    | 1     | 1                     | true      | 0
6    | 0     | 1                     | false     | 1
7    | 1     | 1                     | true      | 0
8    | 0     | 0                     | true      | 0
9    | 1     | 0                     | false     | 1
```

Example:

```js
function pattern(length) {
    var str = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < length; x++ ) {
        if( x % 2 === Math.floor(x / 4) % 2 ){
            str += "0";
        } else {
            str += "1";
        }
    }
    return str;
}


console.log(pattern(10));
console.log(pattern(3));
```

**Another approach:**

You can use an array and fill it with `"01011010"` (basic repeating string, the period) and join it then cut as mush from the string as you want:

```js
function pattern(length) {
  return new Array(Math.ceil(length / 8))          // create the array that will hold the 8-chars strings (length / 8 using ceil for excess) 
             .fill("01011010")                     // fill it with the 8-chars
             .join("")                             // join them
             .slice(0, length);                    // then cut out just what you need
}


console.log(pattern(10));
console.log(pattern(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
var array = [1,0,1,0],times = 5,output = '';
    for(var ix=0;ix<times;ix++){
        array.push(array.shift());
        output += array.join('');
    }
    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this,
I have tested it on my end:

```
 var startPos=0;
    var array=[];
    var to=false;
    for(var i=0;i<16;i++){
if(startPos/4 ==1 || startPos/4 ==2 || startPos/4 ==3 || startPos/4 ==4){
    to=true;
    }
    else{
    to=false;
    }
    if(to){
    if(array){
    if(array[i-1]==1){
    array.push(1);
    to=false;
    }
    else{
    array.push(0);
    }
    }
    }
    else{
    if(array){
    if(array[i-1]==0){
    array.push(1);
    }
    else{
    array.push(0);
    }
    }
    }
    console.log(startPos,array);
    startPos++;
    }
```